# Regular expression for matching lines consisting of only one "AND"

Tags: regex

I'm desperately trying to find a regex that works on regex101 to match
only the first of these two lines (my regex is to filter out those lines that have one than more condition):

```
condition="AND (subject,contains,sd)"
condition="AND (subject,contains,sd) AND (subject,contains,sd) AND
(subject,contains,sd)"
```

My last try was

`(.*)(AND)(.*?)(subject)(.*?\).*)`

I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: Would `subject` always be inside `(...)` ?

Comment: Didn't you post this a couple days ago? Either that or I'm having serious déjà vu.

Comment: just use the count one format

Comment: Just `/.*?AND$/sm` will do.

Comment: `these two lines` there are 3 lines

Comment: `(?m)^(?=.*\bAND\b)(?!(?:.*\bAND\b){2}).+`  https://regex101.com/r/9WteQy/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead like below:

```
"AND\s*\([^)]*\)(?!\s*AND)
```

Explanation:

- **`"AND\s*`**: a beginning AND statement, followed by potential blank spaces
- **`\([^)]*\)`**: followed by a text surrounded by parenthesis
- **`(?!\s*AND)`**: and not followed by potential blank spaces and an AND statement.

[Working sample at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gvQprS/6).

Answer (score 0):

I did a test using the following and it seems to return what you want:

".*"

[image]

being more specific:

"(.+subject.*)"|"(.+contains.*)"

[image]

Comment: PS: I've assumed that the ones with multiple conditions would have a space char after the ")"

Comment: whatever is inside " " will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern at the beginning of each line to filter out those that contain two or more `AND`s:

```
^(?!(?:.*\bAND\b){2,}).*\bAND\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/f2pXN0/2